# Segmentation fault when moving code outside of main()

Tags: c

I am learning C, and was testing out using a library - the openssl library to be exact. I got the SHA function working successfully. Then when I moved the working code (posted below) outside of the main method to a method that I called (literally the same code), it created a segmentation fault when I tried to execute.

```
const char *input = "hashthisstring"; unsigned char *result;

SHA1((const unsigned char *)input, strlen(input), result);

int i; for (i = 0; i<SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)  printf("%02x",
result[i]); printf("\n");
```

I thought I understood segmentation fault errors to be when we are trying to access memory locations which can't be accessed. But I am confused here - the code is identical! Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that `result` is supposed to store the output, but it's just an uninitialized pointer.

According to [the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html):

> SHA1() computes the SHA-1 message digest of the n bytes at d and places it in md (**which must have space for SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH == 20 bytes of output**). If md is NULL, the digest is placed in a static array.

So you'll want to do something like this:

```
unsigned char *result = malloc(SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
// make sure to free(result) eventually
```

Or just do it on the stack if you want this to be simpler and don't need to return the result.

```
unsigned char result[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

Most likely it worked before because `result` just happened to be pointing at a memory location that your program was allowed to access.